# How do you get HTML code not the source code when web scraping?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-scraping, phantomjs

Currently I'm using phantom JS and returning page. Content, however this returns the source code not the current page HTML.

the website loads and then the product list loads. the product list is not a part of the source code and isn't returned when requesting page. Content.
Apparently this is a common problem with Phantom JS.

Has anyone got any suggestions of other methods/packages what will return the current Page HTML.

my project is a C# Windows forms project.

many thanks

Comment: "Apparently this is a common problem with Phantom JS."...I'd say not really, it's simply a problem with all sites which load content via separate AJAX requests, after the initial request.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, you were right and got it working now through the copying XHR requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try selenium webdriver and use WebDriverWait to catch the loaded products list, this is the easiest option ... another option try to reverse engineer the HTTP requests and see if could simulate the JSON files requests in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebClient WC = new WebClient();
string JSON = WC.DownloadString(url);
Object onject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JJs.ITEMS>>(JSON);
```

In the end went to the request recorded in the XHR tab on networking ant it returns a JSON file of the data the webpage uses to generate the product list